# how to set retrofit connections timeout unlimited?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to set **Retrofit** connection timeout **unlimited** instead of **static** timeout 
    connection.how can I do it ?

This is my code...

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

    if (RetrofitInstance==null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        RetrofitInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

    return RetrofitInstance;
}
```

Comment: not aware of infinite but you can set big value like (24Hour) in  .readTimeout(24, TimeUnit.HOURS) and connectTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Retrofit` does not allow developers to remove timeout completely, but you could set `TimeUnit.HOURS` to use big value for your timeout. For example:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .connectTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .build();
```

Used `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for this example, which is big enough value to act as an infinite timeout.

---

Good luck :)